# how to set time and date for sending sms

Tags: android

I want set time  and date  of sending sms when time and date comes then sms send automatically..Now i make successfully make sms sending app  and also time and date picker.....but Now the problem is that how to set time and date for sending like alarm .In which we set time for alarm

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
EditText edittext1,edittext2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);

        }
    } else {
        //do
    }



    edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    String number = edittext1.getText().toString();

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String number = edittext1.getText().toString();
            String sms = edittext2.getText().toString();

            try {
                SmsManager smsmanager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsmanager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Send sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Send sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

    });





    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", number);//sender name
    values.put("body", "this is my text");
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,  int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1:{
            if(grantResults.length>0&& grantResults[0] ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                   Toast.makeText(this,"Premission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "NO premiision granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

I just wanna know that how to press sending button automatically  when set time and date comes...
  thank you

Comment: you want to add date and time in yous sms? actually not getting where you want to add the date and time.

Comment: http://vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html there are lot of tutorial available for creating service in android. Please refer it.

Comment: NO...i just want to send sms automatically at a defined time and date

Answer (score 0):

Try use BroadcastReceiver. You can receive time changed action, and then post your sms

Comment: i tried a lot  using BroadcastReceiver .but not working ...plz give me  demo

Answer (score 0):

In your activity add following code with your required time and date

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);

    if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, aHOUR);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, aMINUTE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, aSECOND);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Now create a broadcast receiver and call sms send function in **OnRecieve()** method.